# App that simulates handling of 0-4 year old babies in their world environment

Tags: android, 3d, game, android-app, parenting

I am looking for a tamogachi-like game, where you can interact with babies.

The babies are aged 0-4 years old.

This would allow prospective parents, teachers, and backporting baby experience people to comprehend and complete, all, of their emotional gaps.

You can have many babies.

And many moms or dads, making stories.

Luckily, they are your mom and dad (in the sense, that, they belong to you, and your well-being (in your interaction with the babies)).

This, would be the game.

The software lets you interact with the baby via a camera.

Different babies are programmed to react differently and uniquely, according to the camera interaction.

You can click it drag to grab in hands arms and stomach.

A baby can do a lot to you.

Let that baby do those things to you.

And, bring about, your imagination.

Teachers would have a good imagination about babies.

Also, parent programmers.

Who will bring on these kind of games.

I am looking for opportunities, ideas, and feedback.

I am looking for such software.

Please, bring on the games.

Thank you for your contributions.

Thanks.

NOTE: Babies want to interact with their environment, siblings, and adults, in their games. But older babies might want games that will allow them and envision them interacting with babies (with all the challenges this brings on).

I am looking for a forward view that lets you see your hands and body as you view your baby, wash it, dress it, teach it words, react to its whims and cries, cuddle it, put it to sleep, and so on.

You may even select things to say to it and it may react in various ways. I think software developers could do something here. Also, the baby could do different things, and have different ways of keeping on that engagement.

The game should be good enough to give clues as to how to interact with 0-7 year olds.